# How to change table data with Django and Ajax

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a pandas dataframe that I am displaying in a Django Template as follows

views.py

```
def display(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        temp_df_path = './temp_match.csv'
        option = 'all'
        animals_data = helper(temp_df_path, options=option)
        
        json_records = animals_data.reset_index().to_json(orient='records') 

        data = []
        data = json.loads(json_records)
        
        context = {'d': data, 'data_columns': animals_data.columns}

        return render(request, 'results.html', context=context)
```

Here I am displaying a DataFrame filtered using the helper function. In the template I have a set of radio buttons with which I can change the `option` variable. Here is my template

```
<div class="container center">
    <div class="table_options action_panel_centered">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"
                checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Show all animals</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Show only carnivores</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Show only herbivores</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid root center">
    <div class="table_container">
        <table class="table table-hover" id='results_table'>
            <tr>
                <th class="index_th">#</th>
                {% for col in data_columns %}
                <th>{{col}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
                <th class='action_cell'>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            {% if d %}
            {% for i in d %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    {{forloop.counter}}
                </th>
                ...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the content using Ajax. How do I do that? I have an Ajax function as follows

```
function change_content(event) {
    $.post(
         url : {% url 'display' %},
         success: function(data, status, xhr){
            //do something with your data
        }
    );
    return false;
}

$(function () {
    $('.form-check-input').click(change_content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a separate HTML page containing only the table contents that
   you want to load when the button changes (usually ).
2. Then write a function in the backend to render this page. pass necessary
   parameters to the function for filtering your query and pass data to the page you are rendering.
3. After that write an AJAX function in the
   frontend and make a call to the above function with the necessary
   params, in the success response just replace the table contents with
   the incoming data.